# Read GET array in PHP but no work

Tags: php, arrays, get

I have URL for ajax:

```
index.php?order[0][column]=2&&order[0][dir]=asc
```

And use for print the value:

```
echo $_GET["order"][0][dir];
```

But no work...

Comment: Not really enough to get an answer. Try to add a more complete code sample.

Comment: echo $_GET['order'][0]['dir']; use single quotes.

Comment: To check what is in your $_GET array add this simple debugging tool to your code `print_r($_GET);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing the quotes on "dir".
Ex:
$_GET["order"][0]["dir"]